# fuzzyfinder not working in gvim

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I found out about fuzzyfinder yesterday and tried installing it. Then found out I needed L9 since that is a prerequisite for fuzzyfinder.

I am getting the following errors when running gvim:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/fuf.vim:
line   13:
***** L9 library must be installed! *****
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/l9.vim:
line    8:
E117: Unknown function: l9#guardScriptLoading
E15: Invalid expression: !l9#guardScriptLoading(expand('<sfile>:p'), 702, 0, [])
line   16:
E117: Unknown function: l9#defineVariableDefault
```

I've put `fuf.vim` and `l9.vim` into my `plugin` folder.  I tried putting them in `autoload` folder as well but that fetches even more errors.

My version is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr 16 2010 12:40:58)`

Googling did not work since question from one mailing list is spread of so many other links and the answer is nowhere to be found.

Comment: You are supposed to put all your plugins/colorschemes/etc in `~/.vim`. Try that, then close and relaunch Vim. Then install the plugins (FF & L9) with all the files in the correct place. Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: nice rep, Omnipresent :)

Comment: ...ok I was slow :) my rep at the time was "1337" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both fuzzyfinder and l9 plugins contain more then one file. They must not work if you have thrown away most of them (and you did if you put just fuf.vim and l9.vim). You are supposed to unpack plugin archives into ~/.vim.

By the way, you may try to use [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905). Copy the following into your shell and you should get FuzzyFinder successfully installed with an advantage of having each plugin in a separate directory and easier installation of plugins with dependencies in future:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vam
git clone git://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager ~/.vam/vim-addon-manager
echo 'set rtp+=~/.vam/vim-addon-manager' >> ~/.vimrc
echo 'call vam#ActivateAddons(["FuzzyFinder"])' >> ~/.vimrc
vim # Now answer yes on all queries
```

While this is correct the VAM team proposes reading the official documentation about how to install VAM which can be found at github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager then cd into the doc directory.
We want to be fair and say that VAM is only one solution. Vundle, Pathogen, ... and some more exist (See related work section in docs of VAM)

Comment: For everybody using copy and paste: --strip-componets should be --strip-components