# Can't install FuzzyFinder in vim

Tags: macos, vim, plugins, osx-lion, fuzzyfinder

I download `vim-fuzzyfinder` into my downloads folder. I move the folder (containing `autoload/`, `doc/`, and `plugin/` to `~/.vim/bundle/` (I'm using Pathogen, by the way). I start up vim and get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/archio/.vim/bundle/vim-fuzzyfinder/plugin/fuf.vim  
line   13:
***** L9 library must be installed! *****
```

What happened? How can I get this to work? I'm fairly new to vim plugins.

Comment: Note: I believe this is on topic, see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765229/fuzzyfinder-not-working-in-gvim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plugin in question appears to have a dependency on the [L9 library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3252), which I hadn't come across either so far. Just install the L9 library and retry.

Ah, and there is an alternative called the [CtrlP plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736), and it is pretty good, especially, at least for me, when taking the fuzz out for straight matching as per the instructions given on the Vim mailing list archives in this [MangoldSchinkenCannelloni message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/U6L33ZWvfj4/103elwelSc0J).

Comment: Wow, am I an idiot. There it is in the docs for FuzzyFinder: "Requirements: L9 library". Thanks!